# strange styles in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've found some strange build-in styles in chrome v. 39.0.2171.95m:

```
::content div[id^="cpa_rotator_block"], ::content div[id^="rtn4p"], ::content div[id^="sblock_inform_"], ::content img[width="120"][height="600"], ::content img[width="160"][height="600"], ::content img[width="468"][height="60"], ::content img[width="728"][height="90"], ::content noindex > .search_result[class*="search_result_"], ::content .a-buttons.blue-but.a-check, ::content .a-buttons.green-but.a-clock, ::content div[style="width: 252px; height: 450px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 10000;"], ::content #pgeldiz, ::content .rbcobmen, ::content #banner.b-banner__content, ::content .b-spec-adv, ::content .serp-adv, ::content .spec-adv, ::content .stat_pixel_yes[onclick][class*="_layout_"][class*="_format_"], ::content .min-width-normal > #popup_container, ::content .min-width-normal > #popup_container ~ #fade {

display: none;

}
```

Does anybody know what are they for? I can't change it, cuz chrome returns that styles and rules, and it doesn't even interrupts with `display: block !important`

P.S. That's AdBlock.

Comment: You have some adware installed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most commonly used in regular expressions to **designate the beginning of a string**.

If we want to target all anchor tags that have a href which begins with http, we could use a selector similar to the snippet shown below.

```
a[href^="http"] {
   background: url(path/to/external/icon.png) no-repeat;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[**Useful Link**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) - See No. 13

Comment: Yea, I know for what that selectors are used. I don't understand why chrome has execly that styles? Especially this one: [style="width: 252px; height: 450px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 10000;"]

Comment: Why do you think it's Chrome? the site developer must have coded them.

Comment: If you have adblock installed deactivate it and check if it gives you the same result :)

Comment: That's it! I didn't event thought that custom-html content could be blocked by adblock :) Thank you!